# Why am i receiving an Application defined or object defined error for code that counts the last row in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing this macro so that I can copy a range of cells in one worksheet and dynamically paste over the last 13 rows of data in another worksheet and also paste data into the bottom row.  Every time I attempt to run this code below I receive a *Application defined or object defined error* and the debugger in my vba editor highlights this line of code: `lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row` as the source of the error.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong???

```
Sub DataTransfer()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("B3:P16").Copy
ws2.Range("G" & lastRow - 11 & ":P" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: You must ensure that lastRow - 11 is >= 1.   If you have no data in sheet (ws2) then lastrow=1 and lastRow - 11 becomes -10.  The code is good and works if have already data in column G at least up to line 12

Comment: Change `Dim lastRow As Integer` to `Dim lastRow As Long`, Integers only go up to 32,767, rows to 1,048,576

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ there’s data in column G. Cell G1 is blank and cells G2:G3 are merged and contains text.  The table contains data from cells G4 all the way down to G169.  Could the merged cells be causing the issue???

Comment: @CDP1802 I ran into the same issue using Long datatype.  This worksheet only has 400 rows so I doubt that’s the issue.

Comment: try replacing xlUp with value `.End(-4162).Row`

Comment: @cdp1802 Ok this works! What made you think to make this suggestion?

Comment: Educated guesswork :) What version of excel / windows are you ? Have you upgraded recently ?

Comment: `l` and `1` do look similar i.e. `x1up` (wrong) and `xlUp` (correct) are not the same. This would have never happened if you would have used `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes.  I have M365.  I also just realized that my copied range was not the same size as the range with the attached to the ```.PasteSpecial``` method.  I think that is what was causing the error because it worked even when I use ```.End(xlUp).Row```.   Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score -1):

I just realized that my copied range was not the same size as the range with the `.PasteSpecial` method attached to it.  I changed the last line to
`ws2.Range("G" & lastRow - 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` and it fixed everything.